# Fuzzy tag matching with acts-as-taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on, fuzzy-search

So I'm using **acts_as_taggable** on a model. I'd like to be able to find tags with some sort of a `%LIKE%` matching, but I'm not sure how.

My current code:

```
@companies = Company.tagged_with(@query, :any => true)
```

doing this doesn't work:

```
tagged_with("%#{@query}%", :any => true)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No it wont work. That isnt how acts_as_taggable was written to work. When you submit a taglist it generates a list of all tags from your query string and uses it to fetch tagged records. It doesnt make a search on the list of tags to find the tags that match your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by fetching the tags manually first

```
  tags = Tag.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{@query}%").pluck(:name)
  @companies = Company.tagged_with(tags, :any => true)
```

However, this required my to create an empty `Tag` model, which isn't created by acts_as_taggable.

Maybe not the best solution, but it works :)
I'll rather do this "hack", then to write my own tagging models.

Answer (score 1):

```
@companies = Company.tagged_with('query', wild: true)
```

You should try it.

> You can also use :wild => true option along with :any or :exclude option. It will be looking for %awesome% and %cool% in SQL